# Почему после импорта публичных gpg ключей становятся доступны секретные ключи?

Tags: linux, шифрование, gpg, pgp

Подскажите, почему после импорта публичных gpg ключей становятся доступны секретные ключи? Допустим у меня было 3 саб ключа (primary удален) на A, E и S, затем я удаляю E саб ключ, следовательно его более не существует в системе, потом я импортирую публичные ключи и каким то образом удаленный секретный саб ключ E восстанавливается, хотя я его не импортировал.

Comment: возможно неправильно экспортировал публичный ключь и там прицепился  приватный, возможно не там смотришь список ключей

Comment: Можно код, которым смотришь ключи?